# Is there any way to lower the difficulty in order to mine faster on a testnet?

Tags: mining, testnet, difficulty

I'm searching for a way to mine 60 blocks without the waiting time (or at least significantly reduce the time) on a testnet.
Can it be done or will it affect other operations in the blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a local testnet (that is, you don't need to accept blocks from other peers, nor get peers to accept your blocks), then you can hardcode a fixed difficulty in src/cryptonote_basic/difficulty.cpp, returning a small value in next_difficulty. A value equal to your hash rate will get you a block every 2 minutes on average. A value equal to your hash rate divided by 20 will get you a block every 6 second on average, etc.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Just used the `--fixed-difficulty` flag when using `--testnet`.

Comment: Only works with *very* recent master.

Comment: If you're doing testnet stuff you are almost always on master no? If you are cloning the repo and making code changes, you're most likely on master too.

Answer (score 0):

No code changes needed:

`$ monerod --help | grep fixed
  --fixed-difficulty arg (=0)           Fixed difficulty used for testing.`